# \part command before facing pages

Tags: parts, eledmac, eledpar

Currently I'm typesetting a book where I want to you the `\part*{}` sectioning command to separate a preface from a text edition that uses faceing pages (eledmac/eledpar).

The problem is that I get two blank pages between the part-title and the beginning of the edition. I guess its because the edition has to start on a even pagenumber (right) and the part command adds a blank page to have the next chapter printed on a odd pagenumber (rightsided).

My favourite option would be to have a part-title on the rightside and the beginning of the edition directly on the following leftside. If you have any advice I'd be very happy.

The following example could serve as an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR=12mm,DIV=14]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface Blablabla}

\part*{Edition}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Edition}

\renewcommand*{\goalfraction}{0.9}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Blablabla
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
Blablabla
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
{\renewcommand\partheademptypage{}
\addpart{Edition}}
```

`\addpart{Edition}` does the same as `\part*{Edition}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Edition}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR=12mm,DIV=14]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface Blablabla}

{\renewcommand\partheademptypage{}
\addpart{Edition}}

\renewcommand*{\goalfraction}{0.9}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Blablabla
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
Blablabla
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[...]
\begin{document}
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
  \chapter*{Preface Blablabla}  
  \part*{Edition}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Edition}%
}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fast reply. It solves the blank pages problem perfectly. Is there also a way to get the part-title on the right side instead of the left side as it turn out at the moment?

Comment: Isn't page number 2 not the right page in your example?

Comment: Maybe it's better to call it recto and verso. I would like to have the part-title recto and the first of the parallel pages verso on the same paper. In the above case I have them both verso on two following pages. But thanks for the code. It was helpful to get an idea on the approach.